# How to let a thread remember which number it is in C pthread forever until destroyed?

Tags: c, multithreading, static

I have to create multiple threads and use them for multiple times. I need to let each thread remember that it is the i-th thread (not the system thread id). Thus there need to be a static place in the thread function. However, static variables can only be initiated with constant values. On the other hand, since the threads are used for multiple times, their void *arg will change through time. Thus they have to hold their number forever since creation. How to do this?

I tried to first store all thread numbers in a global array. However, letting each thread remember its corresponding array index still faces the same problem.

```c
sem_t begin_sem, finish_sem;
int thr_nums[100];
int num;
void **thr_args;
pthread_t *threads;
void *thr_func(void *arg);

struct rusage main_usage;        // get usage for main thread


int create_mat_vec_mul(int thr_count)
{
    int i;
    num = thr_count;
    thr_args = calloc((size_t) thr_count, sizeof(void *));
    threads = calloc((size_t) thr_count, sizeof(pthread_t));
    sem_init(begin_sem, 0, 1);
    for (i = 0; i < thr_count; ++i) {
        thr_nums[i] = i;
        thr_args[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(void *));
        thr_args[i] = thr_nums + i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < thr_count; ++i) {
        pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, thr_func, (void *) thr_args[i]);
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < thr_count; ++i) {
        free(thr_args[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void *thr_func(void *arg)
{
    static int *this_num_ptr = arg; // this is erroneous
    sem_wait(&begin_sem);
    
}
```

Comment: Why does `this_num_ptr` need to be `static`?

Comment: You have other problems though: `thr_args[i] = ...` directly followed by `thr_args[i] = ...` What do you think happens with the first value you assign to `thr_args[i]`?

Comment: Also, you can actually pass `int` values to a thread function, with the right casting. When creating the thread do `pthread_create(..., (void *) (intptr_t) i)`, and in the thread function `int this_num = (int) (intptr_t) arg;` No need to bother with all the arrays and dynamic allocation and the memory leak etc.

Comment: And about the `static` again... Do you really know what `static` means for local variables? It means that the function only have *one* variable, shared for *all* calls. Which is really not what you want. So the simple solution is simply to not make it `static`, and you will solve multiple problems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you. What I want to do is to initialize the partial multiplication threads once, and use them to multiply matrices to vectors in parallel in the future for many times. Therefore I think there is no chance to tell the threads about their numbers. So I think that they must retain a static variable to remember their numbers forever. For the multiple assignments to thr_args[i], that is indeed a mistake.

Comment: If this was allowed, then because the variable is `static` *all* threads will have the exact same value, which will be the value of the last thread function that was called. A normal non-`static` local variable will have its life-time last the entire function, which for a thread function will be equal to the life-time of the thread itself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OK now I understand. Thank you very much.